# Route are not working in vanilla Javascript SPA

Tags: javascript, php, routes, single-page-application

I am working on a single page application, now stuck at routing, I have tried different ways but my code always returns 404. I need some help now

```
const route = (event) => {
  event = event || window.event;
  event.preventDefault();
  window.history.pushState({}, "", event.target.href);
  handleLocation();
};

const routes = {
  404: 404. php ',  // http://localhost/spa/404.php',
  'index': 'index.php',
  'preparing': 'preparing.php',
  'completed': 'completed.php',
};

console.log("routes ", routes);

const handleLocation = async() => {
  const path = window.location.href;
  const route = routes[path] || routes[404];
  console.log("routes", route);
  const html = await fetch(route).then((data) => data.text());
  document.getElementById("main-nav").innerHTML = html;
};

window.onpopstate = handleLocation;
window.route = route;

handleLocation();
```

Comment: `window.location.href;` returns the full URL, not just the path. So there is no way that any of the routes can be selected. Try to read the `location.pathname` property and change your routes to resemble the `pathname` value.

Comment: Thanks, Emiel Zuurbier - i matched but still its nor working see console https://postimg.cc/Vdkgqhf0

Comment: Well, not really. The string that `location.pathname` will output is `/spa/index.php`. And that's not a key in your `routes` object. So either you manipulate the output from `location.pathname` so that it matches a key in your object or you write the keys in your `routes` object like the output of `location.pathname`.

Comment: No idea if it's related, but code that seems to address these issues is over at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75266770/6243352).